Testing TypeScript code compiled with the module: none option
I have TypeScript code, being compiled with the "module": "none" option and single output JavaScript file. I need a JavaScript code that I can run directly in the browser console.
I want to write tests for my TypeScript code. I tried using Jest, but it seems to require import syntax, which isn't an option for me because import isn't compatible with the browser cosnole so I wouldn't be able to run my compiled JavaScript in the console.
What tool and approach can I take to test my TypeScript code while keeping the "module": "none" option, single output file and JavaScript code that can run in the browser console?
